# Display custom Modal dynamically in react app

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

In a react app, I'm trying to display a modal with a form. Any suggestions on how to do that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://reactstrap.github.io/components/modals/#app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since usually there is only one modal at the same moment on your screen, it's a pretty common practice to use `Context/Provider` for this purpose. First you need to create context for your modal:

```js
const ModalContext = React.createContext();
```

Then your own ModalProvider:

```js
const ModalProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [ modal, setModal ] = React.useState(null);

  const showModal = renderProp => setModal(renderProp);
  const hideModal = () => setModal(null);

  return (
    <ModalContext.Provider value={ showModal }>
      { children }
      { modal && (
        <div className="overlay" />
        { renderProp(hideModal) }
      ) }
    </ModalContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Own modal provider should wrap your app on some root level:

```js
const App = () => (
  <ModalProvider>
    <LandingPage />
  </ModalProvider>
);
```

Then, you just need to use this context in any component to show modal:

```js
const renderModal(hideModal) => {
  // call hideModal to hide modal
};

const Page = () => {
  const showModal = useContext(ModalContext);

  const onClick = showModal(renderModal);

  return (
    <Button onClick={ onClick }>Show Modal!</Button>
  );
}
```

If you already have redux in your app you can use it for the same purpose - by setting some global state with modal data:

```js
const modalReducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case SHOW_MODAL:
      return { ...state, modal: payload };
    case HIDE_MODAL:
      return { ...state, modal: null };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```